# The GNS construction and a Radon-Nikodym-like formula

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, radon-nikodym

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $W^{*}$-algebra, $\omega$ a normal, positive linear functional on $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathbf{p}$ the support projection of $\omega$, and $(\mathcal{H},\pi,\psi)$ the GNS triple associated with $\omega$.

If $S$ is a densely-defined self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with $\psi$ in its domain, then the linear functional $\xi$ on $\mathcal{A}$ defined by
$$
\xi(\mathbf{a}):=\langle\phi|\pi(\mathbf{a})|\psi\rangle + \langle \psi|\pi(\mathbf{a})|\phi\rangle
$$
with $\phi=S\psi$, is a bounded, normal, self-adjoint linear functional on $\mathcal{A}$.

Clearly, $\xi(\mathbf{a})=0$ for all $\mathbf{a}\in\,\mathbf{q}\mathcal{A}\mathbf{q}$ with $\mathbf{q}=\mathbb{I}-\mathbf{p}$.

I am wondering if the converse is also true, and/or there are other assumptions needed for the converse to hold.

In some sense, this would be a sort of (linear) Radon-Nikodym theorem along the lines of the paper by [Maltese-Niestegge](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_1987_4_14_2_345_0.pdf).

Comment: Not entirely sure what you expect the "converse" to be.

Comment: That every $\xi$ such that $\xi(\mathbf{a}^{\dagger}\mathbf{a})=0$ for every $\mathbf{a}^{\dagger}\mathbf{a}\in\mathbf{q}\mathcal{A}\mathbf{q}$ admits a representation as the one in the body of the question.